# mysql-find rows that source id have only one dest id

Tags: mysql, sql

`transferHistory` table:

```
╔════════════╦════════╗
║ sourceId   ║ destId ║
╠════════════╬════════╣
║       221  ║ 1      ║
║      2223  ║ 1      ║
║      2223  ║ 2      ║
║        44  ║ 3      ║
║        33  ║ 3      ║
║        55  ║ 3      ║
║        44  ║ 2      ║
╚════════════╩════════╝
```

So I want to find all rows where the destId is a given id and the given id was the only destination id of the source id.

Example:

given dest id = 1, result should be 221 (because source 2223 is divided to two destination 1 and 2)

given dest id = 2, result should be empty(because source 2223 and 44 are both divided to two destination )

given dest id = 3, result should be 33 and 55.

How do I write a SQL to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want source ids where there is no other dest id.  This suggests `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.destId = @destId and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.sourceId = t.sourceId and
                        t2.dest_id <> t.dest_id
                 );
```

You can drop the `t.destId = @destId` if you want all rows that match the condition.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just look for the sourceId's which only have one destination i.e.

```
SELECT sourceId, destId
FROM transferHistory t
GROUP BY sourceId
HAVING COUNT(sourceId) = 1
```

Output:

```
sourceId    destId
33          3
55          3
221         1
```

If you want to get them only for a specific destId, add that to the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT sourceId, destId
FROM transferHistory t
GROUP BY sourceId
HAVING COUNT(sourceId) = 1 AND destID = 3
```

Output:

```
sourceId    destId
33          3
55          3
```

Comment: Hi I used the one with specific dest source id and got ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: here is my sql: `select th
from transfer_histories th
group by th.source_id
having count(th.source_id) = 1 and th.dest_id = 123;`

Comment: It should be `select th.source_id, th.dest_id from transfer_histories th group by th.source_id having count(th.source_id) = 1 and th.dest_id = 123;`

Comment: Or `select * from transfer_histories th group by th.source_id having count(th.source_id) = 1 and th.dest_id = 123;` if there are other fields you want to select as well.